# Bot Framework Channel Emulator has invalid channel ID?

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm using the C# Bot Framework library to retrieve some data from the Bot State Service. Whenever `channelId == "emulator"` in the code below, it fails with a `400 Bad Request`. It looks like both Emulator versions 3.0.0.59 and 3.5.27 use this channel ID. Here's the returned payload:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "Invalid channel ID"
  }
}
```

Note that if I change `channelId` to something else like `"skype"`, it works as expected.

```
var credentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(id, password);
this.botState = new BotState(new StateClient(credentials));
var channelId = activity.ChannelId;
await botState.GetUserDataAsync(channelId, activity.From.Id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Received this answer](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/179#issuecomment-299608983) from the Bot Framework team:

> For emulator they need to use the activity’s serviceurl when create the state client. Builder automatically does that in the connector client factory:
>
> https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ConnectorEx/IConnectorClientFactory.cs#L86
>
> ```
> if (IsEmulator(this.address))
> {
>     // for emulator we should use serviceUri of the emulator for storage
>     return new StateClient(this.serviceUri, this.credentials);
> }
> ```
>
> That error is from state.botframework.com (which is the default endpoint for stateclient) since emulator is not a valid channelid for the state service.